# Getting Script on error on following Jquery function

Tags: jquery

```
var clickable = ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn"));
setTimeout(clickable, 1000);
```

But if I call it like this there is no script error pop up :

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn"));
```

The method is as follows :

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass = function(selectedElements) {
    // Go through each of the passed in selections and try to apply a link to them
    $.each(selectedElements, function() {
        var linkElement = $("a:first:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link)", $(this));
        var link = linkElement.attr("href");
        if (!IsNullEmptyOrUndefined(link)) {
            $(this).click(function(firstLink) {
                var divToLink = firstLink;
                return function() {
                    $(divToLink).unbind('click');
                    if (divToLink.attr("target") != "_blank") {
                        window.location = link;
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            }(linkElement));
        }
    });
}
```

The error is just a js popup "An error has occured in the Script on this page"

Comment: If you use FireBug (FireFox) or IE 9's F12 you can get better diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clickable` variable is set to the return value from *calling* the `ApplyClickableLinkToClass` function, which is undefined. So by passing `clickable` to `setTimeout` you're passing undefined.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn"))
}, 1000);

// OR

var clickable = function() {
   ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn"))
}

setTimeout(clicable, 1000);
```

Comment: also can you see what that function is supposed to do, because it doesnt open links in a new windowe because thats what I expected

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` expects the first argument to be a function, or the source code you want to execute, as a string (this version is generally deprecated). But you're passing in the *result* of your `ApplyClickableLinkToClass()` function, not the function itself.

You want something like:

```
var clickable = function() {
    ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn"));
};
setTimeout(clickable, 1000);
```

Comment: And does this still actually run the ApplyClickableLinkToClass function ?